# An Error in JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SKIN TYPE</title>

    <script>
      function setText(){
        var oTxt=document.getElementById('txt1');

        oTxt.value='abcdef';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="txt1" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="change text" onclick="setText()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Why do I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Comment: Because you don't have a Element with and ID `txt1` the Type is not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't define `id` to text box.
2. You are declaring `type` two times.

```js
function setText(){
  var oTxt=document.getElementById('txt1');
  oTxt.value='abcdef';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SKIN TYPE</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
    <input type="button" value="change text" onclick="setText()" />
  </body>
</html>
```